# cannot add erratic urdf in gazebo

Tags: ros, urdf, xacro, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am using gazebo 1.9 with ROS Groovy. I want to add an erratic robot in the willowgarage world. In order to do so I have the follwing launch file:

```
<launch>

  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="worlds/willowgarage.world"/> <!-- Note: the world_name is with respect to GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environmental variable -->
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find erratic_description)/urdf/erratic.urdf.xacro" />

<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model erratic" />

</launch>
```

This example file worked perfectly with pr2, but when I launch it I get the following error:

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package smart_arm_description not found
[librospack]: error while executing command
[FATAL] [1374747130.949047781]: Package[smart_arm_description] does not have a path
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
```

I cannot find this smart_arm_description package, can someone help me?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68890/cannot-add-erratic-urdf-in-gazebo/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2013-07-29**:
did you find any solution? i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, This issue is resolved by removing following lines from materials.urdf.xacro file located in erratic_description/urdf.

```
<material name="GunMetalBrushedAluminum">
    <texture filename="package://smart_arm_description/Media/materials/textures/gun_metal_brushed_aluminum.jpg" />
</material>
```

However, The erratic robot still doesn't get spawned in gazebo. Everything goes alright just like PR2 tutorial but not sure whats the problem. I asked this question on gazebo community [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3995/spawning-erratic-robot-in-gazebo-19-with-ros/) you can follow it.

---

Originally posted by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) with karma: 235 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0